# on page load clone first image from collection of photos

Tags: jquery

On my page I'm getting collection of photos, and I store them as thumbs below showImage div which needs to be refreshed with cloned image onclick. **Basically everything is ok except I need to populate this showImage div onpage load with first image**, and then to use this onclick clone which already works.

```
<a href="/Property/GetImage/someIntId">
  <img id="someIntId" class="details" width="100" height="100" src="/Property/GetImage/7" alt="">
</a>

function onPopUp() {
        $(".details").click(function (event) {
            //clone the clicked image
            var clone = $(this).clone();
            clone.height("250px").width("280px");
            //place it in the placeholder
            $('div#showImage').html(clone);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what your looking for?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onPopUp() {
    $(".details").click(function (event) {
        //clone the clicked image
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        clone.height("250px").width("280px");
        //place it in the placeholder
        $('div#showImage').html(clone);
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="onPopUp()">
<a href="/Property/GetImage/someIntId">
   <img id="someIntId" class="details" width="100" height="100" src="/Property/GetImage/7" alt="">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

OR, do you use jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function onPopUp() {
    $(".details").click(function (event) {
        //clone the clicked image
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        clone.height("250px").width("280px");
        //place it in the placeholder
        $('div#showImage').html(clone);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: yep, I need body onload, but before that I figure it out that I need to know first image id on every collection which I need to pass to load that first image. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Are you using PHP? Or pure html & js?

Comment: nope, I'm using c#, updated question here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803927/jquery-clone-image